# How to convert a string (one single column) to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is a string :

```
text = '''10 February 2023
abc
def
23 March 2023
ghi
jkl'''
```

I made the code below (using regex but I'm open to any other alternative) :

```
data = []

for m in re.finditer(r'(\d+ \w+ \w+)\n(.*)', text, flags=re.I|re.S):
    data.append([m.group(1), m.group(2).splitlines()])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'letters']).explode('letters')
```

My code gives me this weird result :

```
               date        letters
0  10 February 2023            abc
0  10 February 2023            def
0  10 February 2023  23 March 2023
0  10 February 2023            ghi
0  10 February 2023            jkl
```

While I was expecting this one :

```
               date        letters
0  10 February 2023            abc
0  10 February 2023            def
1     23 March 2023            ghi
1     23 March 2023            jkl
```

How can I fix my code ? Also, do you have any alternatives to suggest ? I'd be very interested to learn from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option without regex, taking advantage of date recognition by [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': text.splitlines()})
m = pd.to_datetime(df['letters'], errors='coerce').notna()

out = df.assign(date=df['letters'].where(m).ffill()
                ).loc[~m, ::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative syntax:

```
s = pd.Series(text.splitlines())
m = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce').notna()

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': s.where(m).ffill(), 'letters': s}
                  )[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
               date letters
0  10 February 2023     abc
1  10 February 2023     def
2     23 March 2023     ghi
3     23 March 2023     jkl
```

Comment: Just to play the Devil's advocate, why your codes give different index than my expected one ? Besides that, thank you so much. Your answer is full of new tricks to me but I'd also be very grateful if you can fix my regex pattern.

Comment: @VERBOSE because the intermediate DataFrame before filtering has 6 rows, but you can add `.reset_index(dropTrue)` is this is important

Comment: Regarding the regex you might want to ask a separate question for that (a pure regex question, no pandas), but I believe you'll have to use a negative look-ahead (`re.finditer(r'(\d+ \w+ \w+)\n((.(?!\d+ \w+ \w+))*)', text, flags=re.I|re.S))`) which might not be super efficient. Here you already have lines, take advantage of that instead of trying to match over the newlines ;)